# A <FORM> element disappears from the DOM

Tags: html

A fragment of my web output, when seen under Sources in Chrome Development Tools and Debugger in Edge is:

```
  </div>
  <form id="form" style="display:none;">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor"></textarea>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="discard();" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </form>
  <!--**END**-->
```

However, under Elements in Chrome and DOM Explorer in Edge, the `<form>` element is missing, as follows:

[image]

Though I have some scripts, none of them did anything to the `<form>` element. What could be causing the anomaly?

Comment: Can you share the whole Html. It seen to me some semantic issue or tag closing issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check your `DOM`. Form element can not generate as a nested.
may be there is another form element exist in parent tag.

Comment: Spot on! Somewhere in the content of the page there was the text `<FORM>` and it wasn't HtmlEncoded. I lost four hours on this.